# Breaking out of for loop for current irteration

Tags: python, loops, break

I have a loop with a conditional check at some point, is there a way that I can exit the current iteration if the condition is true but still continue looping.

```
dummy = ['One','Two','Three','Four','Five']

for i in dummy:
    print('Stage 1')
    if i == 'Three':
        break
    print('Stage 2')
```

This code gives me:

```
Stage 1
Stage 2
Stage 1
Stage 2
Stage 1
```

But I would like this:

```
Stage 1
Stage 2
Stage 1
Stage 2
--------
Stage 1
--------
Stage 1
Stage 2
Stage 1
Stage 2
```

The highlighted line shows that it skipped the second print statement for element 'Three'.

Thanks

Comment: use `continue` instead of `break`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You meant to use [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) instead of `break`:

```
>>> dummy = ['One','Two','Three','Four','Five']
>>> 
>>> for i in dummy:
...     print('Stage 1')
...     if i == 'Three':
...         continue
...     print('Stage 2')
... 
Stage 1
Stage 2
Stage 1
Stage 2
Stage 1
Stage 1
Stage 2
Stage 1
Stage 2
```

Answer (score -2):

C language offers the continue keyword. Here is an example that prints all odd < 100

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    if((i%2) == 0)
    {
         continue;
    }
    printf("%i\n",i);
}
```

Comment: Note the `python` tag

Comment: Adding a C example to a Python question misses the point. Downvoted.